# Empathy fails to reconnect after awake from suspend

Tags: 12.04, suspend, empathy

Problem: Whenever I suspend in 12.04 and awake my laptop, Empathy doesn't automatically reconnect and I always have to manually log off and log back in again. Any fixes for this bug?

More Details: Running 12.04 and whenever I suspend/hibernate/close laptop lid, when I restore my session, Empathy is never able to reconnect. In the Accounts settings it says "Failed to retrieve your personal information from the server" If I disable and re-enable my account, then it logs back in no problem, but I have to do this little work around every single time I resume from a suspend/hibernate. Is there any way to fix this so that Empathy automatically reconnects? Thanks for any help in advance.

The account in question is a Facebook account (its the only protocol I use)

Comment: This should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) if you have not done so already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a known unsolved problem:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/empathy/+bug/662766
- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=635618

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not ideal, but have you tried Pidgin?

Comment: Yes I've used Pidgin before, great app, but I'm trying to stick with all the default Ubuntu apps as kind of an experiment/trial to see if my needs can be handled by just the default apps shipped in Ubuntu so I'm actually in need of a fix/script/workaround for this little bug. Thanks though!